# Execute a string of PHP code on the command line

Tags: command-line, php

I'd like to be able to run a line of PHP code on the command line similar to how the following options work:

```
perl -e "print 'hi';"
python -c "print 'hi'"
ruby -e "puts 'hi'"
```

I'd like to be able to do:

```
php "echo 'hi';"
```

I've read that there is a `-r` option that can do what I need for php, however it doesn't appear to be available when I try to use it.  I've tried using PHP 5.2.13 and PHP 4.4.9 and neither have an `-r` option available.

I wrote this script (that I called run_php.php) - which works, but I'm not a huge fan of it just because I feel like there should be a more "correct" way to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/php5 -q
<?php echo eval($argv[1]); ?>
```

Is there a `-r` option?  If so, why is it not available when I run `--help`?  If there is no `-r` option, what is the best way to do this (without writing an intermediary script if possible)?

---

Because I don't think it was very clear above, the `-r` option is *not* available to me.  Here is the `php -h` output for both versions of PHP that I'm running.

PHP 4.4.9

```
Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f <file>]
       php <file> [args...]
  -a               Run interactively
  -C               Do not chdir to the script's directory
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse <file>.  Implies `-q'
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -q               Quiet-mode.  Suppress HTTP Header output.
  -s               Display colour syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Display source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.
```

PHP 5.2.13

```
Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f <file>]
       php <file> [args...]
  -a               Run interactively
  -C               Do not chdir to the script's directory
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse <file>.  Implies `-q'
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -q               Quiet-mode.  Suppress HTTP Header output.
  -s               Display colour syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Display source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.
```

There is *no* -r option. When I try to use the `-r` option I get:

> Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Which OS are you running this on?

Comment: @Matthew J Morrison, is this your server or a hosted server?

Comment: @Inkspeak - it is a hosted server (because I'm cheap)

Comment: @Matthew J Morrison, I suspect, as the other answer and comments suggest, that your PHP was compiled sans-CLI support. Your hosting provider may have done that for security concerns.

Comment: @Inkspeak that does appear to be the case.  Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew J Morrison, Of course. Good luck.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Yep, it's there in [PHP 5.2's cli SAPI](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_2/sapi/cli/php_cli.c?revision=293036&view=markup#l155).

If you cannot upgrade and that's the case that there's no such option in PHP 5.2 (I don't have it at hand to test), you can do this:

```
echo "<?php echo \"hi\\n\";" | php

hi
```

Original:

There is indeed a `-r` option (though I'm not sure about PHP 5.2):

```
php -r "echo 'hi';";

hi
```

Just make sure you are using the command line version of PHP. `php --version` should give you something like this (notice "cli"):

```
php --version

PHP 5.3.0 (cli) (built: May 20 2010 19:05:12) (DEBUG)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what the (cli) really means?  I'm pretty sure that is my problem.  My --version output for both versions both say (cgi).

Comment: @Matthew J Morrison It's the SAPI that's built when you compile PHP with the `--enable-cli` option.

Comment: does that mean that if my installation of PHP was not combiled with the --enable-cli option that there is not a post-compile setting to enable cli?

Comment: @Matthew J Morrison It's a separate binary. Maybe it's in your system under a different name/location, maybe not.

Comment: Link is dead now.

Comment: The link is broken: *"An Exception Has Occurred. Unknown location: /php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_2/sapi/cli/php_cli.c. HTTP Response Status. 404 Not Found"*

Answer (score 19):

In new versions of PHP you just type "php -a" and you hop into an interactive mode, where you can experiment with PHP.

Answer (score 6):

An extra semicolon is not required at the end.

You can mention `php -r "echo 'hi';"` instead of `php -r "echo 'hi';";`

Another example (to get the current timestamp at the command line):

```
php -r 'print time()."\n";'
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do it is to use the `-r` flag. However, I've found that it does not allow multiline inputs. To work around that, you can do this:

```
php -r "passthru(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));"
```

Which lets you pipe from standard input, like so:

```
echo -n "echo 'test';" | php -r "passthru(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));"
```

However, to answer the original question, if you do not have the `-r` flag available, it is also possible to use the -f flag - just pass standard input as the file to open: `php -f /dev/stdin`

If you do this, be aware that a) you need to include a blank space at the start of the input, and b) you have to open with `<?php`. Example:

```
echo -ne " <?php\necho 'test';" | php -f /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this page on [PHP command line features](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php), if you haven't already. There are some posts on issues based on OS and double or single quotes.

I would also check the PHP information

> php -i

to see if PHP was [compiled with CLI support disabled](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/configure.php) (--disable-cli).

Comment: The second link is broken (404).

Answer (score 0):

I recently found [psysh](https://psysh.org/), which is an interactive debugger also available from the command line.