# Composer download option not found error

Tags: ssh, download, composer-php

I'm trying to download composer but it doesn't work...
I used the command lines from: https://getcomposer.org/download/
This is the response:

```
    php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r
Content-type: text/html

Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f <file>]
       php <file> [args...]
  -a               Run interactively
  -C               Do not chdir to the script's directory
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse <file>.  Implies `-q'
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -q               Quiet-mode.  Suppress HTTP Header output.
  -s               Display colour syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Display source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.
```

Comment: which php version do you use? Just run `php -v` in the terminal

Comment: I'll check that. Give me a second.

Comment: I am using version 5.2.17

Comment: Can you provide the full output of that command? as it's possible that cli is not enabled

Comment: No sorry, I meant the full output of the `php -v` command

Comment: php -v
PHP 5.2.17 (cgi) (built: Jun  4 2015 17:12:37)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v5.0.7, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend Optimizer v3.3.9, Copyright (c) 1998-2009, by Zend Technologies

Comment: By the info you gave it looks like it's related to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954540/execute-a-string-of-php-code-on-the-command-line

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

[Composer does not support PHP 5.2](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#system-requirements) - you must upgrade to at least 5.3, but remember that security support for PHP 5.3 ended years ago and the most current and only supported version is 5.6 (with version 7.0 just around the corner).

If you are still running PHP 5.2 in production, you should consider upgrading.