# Using php in PuTTY

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to install Composer on my Ionos hosted website. I installed PuTTY on my computer and logged into my website. When I key in the command
**php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"**
I get the error message
**Error in Argument 1, char 2, option not found r**

It then gives me a list of arguments(-a, -b, etc.) and -r is not among them. Isn't this a "standard" argument?

Any and all help for this noob most appreciated.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [execute a string of PHP code on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954540/execute-a-string-of-php-code-on-the-command-line)

Comment: (uiserver):u103188260:~$ php -v
PHP 4.4.9 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Nov  5 2020 16:22:22)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies
(uiserver):u103188260:~$

Comment: PHP 4? This is dead from many years ago. You can try `echo "<?php copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" | php`. Or, better use `curl` or `wget` to download the file and save it locally. I don't remember if PHP 4 was able to use URLs for some file operations. Check the [manual of PHP 4](https://php-legacy-docs.zend.com/manual/php4/en/index).